# Check if generic is 0

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write my own collection. It contains generic values, of course. When I'm trying to check if value of array **_content** isn't null - it works well, but only if user will not use integers.

```
 if (_content[_size - 1] != null)
```

The point is that user can create collection of integers and than array will initialize all values as 0 . So when I'm trying check if value is 0 - it doesn't compile.

```
if (_content[_size - 1] != 0)
```

Specifically doesn't work this method(if collection consists of integers):

```
public void Add(T item)
{
        if (_content[_size - 1] != null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The Array is full");
        if (_size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= _size; i++)
            {
                if (_content[i] == null)
                {
                    _content[i] = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your new collection?  You may be able to handle it more easily with something built in.

Comment: are you looking for `default(T)`?

Comment: Adding doesn't works. I've just added it to the description.

Comment: So you can't add 0(zero) to your collection.

Comment: It looks like you should have a field that indicates the current end position in your array.  So it would initialize to 0 and increment on each add or insert and decrements on each remove.  Then your check would just be if that position is greater than the size and it doesn't matter what values are in your array past that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `default` keyword on generic types, it returns the the default value of that type (i.e. null for reference types, 0 or false etc for value types).

**Edit: Previous example would crash :-)**

So try:

```
!object.Equals(_content[_size - 1], default(T))
```

See comments for another solution too.

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to do is a bad practice, so don't do it.

Your approach reserves one value, namely, zero, to represent "nothing". However, there is a difference between zero and nothing, so your approach would lead to errors when zero is a legitimate value.

Consider what would happen when the user of your collection adds zero for the last number. Your code would think that the cell is empty, and not throw the exception as it should.

A better approach would be to store the actual number of elements that have been set in the collection in your `_size` field. The last element of `_content` is conveniently located at `_content.Length-1`, so your check could be done as follows:

```
if (_content.Length == _size) {
    // InvalidOperationException is more appropriate here,
    // because the error is caused by the state of your collection,
    // rather than any particular argument passed to the method.
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The Array is full");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword to check if a value equals the default of its type, i.e. `null` for classes, `0` for numbers etc.

You also need to use [`Object.Equals(a,b)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154(v=vs.110).aspx) as the `==` operator isn't guaranteed to be available on class `T`, so it will not compile.

So your method could look something like:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_content[_size - 1], default (T)))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The Array is full");
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= _size; i++)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_content[i], default (T)))
            {
                _content[i] = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're getting checking for null is that value types (structs, integers etcs) cannot be compared with null.

You can take a few different approaches here. One is to constrain the types that can be used with the generic collection class. This way, you can ensure that only nullable types (i.e. reference types) are used as type definitions for the collection.

`public class MyCollection<T> where T : class`

Or you can check if the type is a reference type before comparing it to null, using reflection:

`typeof(T).IsValueType`

Don't check for specific types - your issue here is that you are comparing non-nullable types with null.